# Excel - how to have it count across rows with an if... then... formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table with entries across for mild/moderate/severe.

I want it to count one entry as severe, if it appears in a row but only count that once. Then, if no severe count Moderate (with the same rule) and then if no severe or moderate, count mild (again only once).

eg for attached image, would count 2x severe, 1x moderate, 1x mild. [table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETVqL.jpg)

many thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you like Count Unique in Row like in Row 1 unique items are 3 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is with a “helper column”. 
Pick a column that you aren’t using. 
I’ll assume that it is Column `F`, but it could be `Z` or `AF`
or wherever you want to put it. 
We will use this column to identify the highest rating in each row.

In Cell `F1`
(I’m assuming that your data start in Row 1; if not, adjust accordingly), enter

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"severe")>0, "S", IF(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"moderate")>0, "Mo", IF(COUNTIF($A1:$D1, "mild")>0, "Mi", "none")))
```

and drag/fill down for as many rows as you have data.

I hope this is fairly self-explanatory; but, if it isn’t:

- Count the number of cells in Row 1 (range `$A1:$D1`) that contain `severe`
  (case insensitive). 
  If the number is greater than zero, display `S`.
- Otherwise, count the number of cells in the row that contain `moderate`. 
  If the number is greater than zero, display `Mo`.
- Otherwise, count the number of cells in the row that contain `mild`. 
  If the number is greater than zero, display `Mi`.
- Otherwise, display `none`.

You could display the words `severe`, `moderate` and `mild`
if you wanted to. 
Or you could display `1`, `2` and `3`. 
Just be consistent with the below.

- Where you want to count the severe rows, enter `=COUNTIF($F:$F, "S")`.
- Where you want to count the moderate rows, enter `=COUNTIF($F:$F, "Mo")`.
- Where you want to count the mild rows, enter `=COUNTIF($F:$F, "Mi")`.

I have the above formulas in cells `A9`, `B9` and `C9`.

[image: demonstration spreadsheet]

Once you get this working, you can hide the helper column.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that you have Data in Range `A2:D5`.
- To Create list of Unique items write this Array Formula in Cell `A7` & Fill Down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$2, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$6:A6, $A$2:$D$2), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Array Formula in Cell `B7` & Fill Down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$D$3, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$6:B6, $A$3:$D$3), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Array Formula in Cell `C7` & Fill Down.

  ```
      {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$4:$D$4, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$6:C6, $A$4:$D$4), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Array Formula in Cell `D7` & Fill Down.

  ```
      {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$5:$D$5, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$6:D6, $A$5:$D$5), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Write Header `Severe Mild & Moderate` in `A12:C12`.
- Finally write this Formula in cell `A13` & Fill Right.

  ```
      =COUNTIF($A$7:$D$9,A$12)
  ```

**Note:**

*Adjust cell references and Source Data as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern Y this has been down voted ??